# Serialized proxy classes Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a possibility to get the "full" object with associations instead of the proxy classes in doctrine 2?

Because I'm serializing the entity (and relations) but when I deserialize I just get a proxy class back.

The query I'm doing:

```
public function getSnippet($id)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('GvnSnippetryBundle:Snippet')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried that personally (and don't have Doctrine2 at fingertips), but [marking association as `EAGER`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-eager-loading) should do the trick. Hovewer, you'll always load those associated object this way.

As a workaround, try accessing the associated entities before serializing. E.g. if you have followed the advice to encapsulate associated objects collection (and you really should follow it), you just access it with `$snippet->howDidYouCallFunctionThatReturnCollection()`. Doctrine intercepts the request to the `Collection` checks that it's filled with proxies and load it automatically. So, it should be something like:

```
class Snippet{
     //other declarations
    /** OneToMany(targetEntity='Blah', ...)*/
    protected $associations;

    public function getAssociations(){
        return $this->associations; //fills proxies with real data here
    }
}

public function getSnippet($id)
{
    $snippet = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('GvnSnippetryBundle:Snippet')->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));
    $snippet->getAssociations(); //gets only one association
    $snippet->getAssociations2(); //and so on
    return $snippet;
}
```

Note that it's no way a complete code sample, but I assume you know how to map associations. Anyway, review [Working with Objects](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#working-with-objects) and [Association Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html) chapters for more detailed description and code samples.

Answer (score 2):

J0HN's answer is good.

If you want to be more focused, you can force Doctrine to fetch-join the associated entities by creating a custom query (either directly in DQL, or using the QueryBuilder).  To force the association to be loaded, you need both:

1) Join the associated entity
2) Reference that entity in the SELECT

So, in DQL:

```
SELECT f 
FROM Foo f
JOIN f.Bar b
```

This will **not** load the associated Bar, since it's not referenced in the SELECT -- you'll get a proxy instead, while

```
SELECT f, b
FROM Foo f
JOIN f.Bar b
```

will force doctrine to fetch-join your Bars.

HTH